# cmake unable to find CC

Tags: linux, compiling, gcc, cmake

I am newbie in Linux, I am using WSL ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to build a project using cmake file.
I am getting following error:-

```
    CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/CMakeDetermineCCompiler.cmake:49 (message):
  Could not find compiler set in environment variable CC:

  arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard
  -mcpu=cortex-a9 -fstack-protector-strong -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat
  -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security
  --sysroot=/opt/iotgw-sdk/sysroots/cortexa9t2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I got cmake version version `version 3.20.0`, I have also export PATH to gcc using following command:-

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gcc
export CC=gcc
```

But no luck. Please tell me what I am missing here.Thanks

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/gcc` shouldn't be necessary and is likely not useful. Do you actually have the `gcc` package installed (using `apt`)? How did you install cmake-3.20 (since the default for Ubuntu 20.04 appears to be 3.16)?

Comment: I move to cmake-3.20 by removing cmake then installing it. Also , I have gcc version 9.3.0

Comment: ... on re-reading the error message, it looks like the issue is that you have set `CC=arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc` in your environment, and *that* is the compiler that can't be found. Is that intentional? Is your hardware actually ARM?

Comment: I got the issue, path for arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc is different. I need to copy arm-fslc-linux-gnueabi-gcc in right path. Thanks for your effort

Comment: A symbolic link would probably be cleaner that a copy, especially when you update the package.